# Bitmap to Integer routine generating exception

Tags: c#, exception, image-processing, bitmap, bitmapdata

```
    public static bool IsGrayscale(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        return bitmap.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed ? true : false;
    }
```

.

```
    public static int[,] ToInteger(Bitmap image)
    {
        if (Grayscale.IsGrayscale(image))
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)image.Clone();

            int[,] array2d = new int[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];

            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                                     ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                     PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            int bytesPerPixel = sizeof(byte);

            unsafe
            {
                byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

                int paddingOffset = bitmapData.Stride - (bitmap.Width * bytesPerPixel);

                for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++)
                    {
                        int iii = 0;

                        //If there are more than 1 channels...
                        //(Would actually never occur)
                        if (bytesPerPixel >= sizeof(int))
                        {
                            byte[] temp = new byte[bytesPerPixel];

                            //Handling the channels.
                            //PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed == 1 channel == 1 bytesPerPixel == byte
                            //PixelFormat.Format32bpp       == 4 channel == 4 bytesPerPixel == int
                            for (int k = 0; k < bytesPerPixel; k++)
                            {
                                temp[k] = address[k];
                            }

                            iii = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);
                        }
                        else//If there is only one channel:
                        {
                            iii = (int)(*address);
                        }

                        array2d[i, j] = iii;

                        address += bytesPerPixel;
                    }

                    address += paddingOffset;
                }
            }

            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            return array2d;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a grayscale");
        }
    }
```

The exception in the following line:

```
 iii = (int)(*address);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Fast Fourier Transform.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

[image]

What is the cause of that exception?

How can I fix that?

.

.

**P.S.** I am using the following PNG image:

[image]

Comment: To directly use pointers, you have to declare the code section as unsafe.

Comment: @Kevin, I have already declared it as unsafe. Otherwise, it shouldn't have been running.

Comment: Can you post an example picture? Because for me the code is working fine

Comment: @technikfischer, done! take a look, plz.

Comment: How do you load the image? Because using this image the code tells me that it is not grayscale. Or which file format is the original file?

Comment: @technikfischer, https://dotnetfiddle.net/6J03D3

Comment: @technikfischer, I converted it to Grayscale. See the fiddle link.

Comment: public class BitmapToIntegerAndViceVersa__Test
    {
        private static string path = @"scratch.png";

        public static void Run()
        {
            Bitmap scratch = Bitmap.FromFile(path) as Bitmap;

            int[,] integer = Grayscale.ToGrayscaleInteger(scratch);

            //int[,] integer = ImageDataConverter.ToInteger(grayscale);

            Bitmap bitmap = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap(integer);

            PictureBoxForm p = new PictureBoxForm(scratch, bitmap);
            p.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

Comment: I added a answer, if it works for you, please mark it as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistaken `bitmap.Width` for `bitmap.Height` in your loops. You should iterate over the height in the outer loop and over the width in the inner loop, as the stride represents the whole width + the offset of the image. Then you can add `padding` on a line basis, instead for each line traversed. So

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Width; j++)
    {
```

is working. Also, you must swap the array access from `array2d[i, j] = iii` to `array2d[j, i] = iii` as the indices are now belonging to the other dimension of the image

Comment: Also, as a general rule, when looping over x and y... _call the loop variables `x` and `y`_. It makes code a lot more straightforward.